# Echoing date automated git commit

Tags: git, shell, variables, echo

I'm setting up a shell script to be run as a cron job, which would commit and push some regularly updated content to a remote repository. In this case, including the date and time in a commit message is information enough for the target audience.

Here is the script in question:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /Users/me/Documents/myfile/
git add .
git commit -m 'Added notes for $(date)'
git push -u origin master
```

This script works, but with one hitch: the commit messages literally all say "`Added notes for $(date)`," instead of including the date and time of the commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes instead:

```
git commit -m "Added notes for $(date)"
```

With single quotes `$(date)` is not expanded and retains a literal form.

As noted [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
>   ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters
>   ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see
>   Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when
>   followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or
>   newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of
>   these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without
>   a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted
>   within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled,
>   history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double
>   quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’
>   is not removed.
>
> The special parameters ‘*’ and ‘@’ have special meaning when in double
>   quotes (see Shell Parameter Expansion).